# How to open other pages in reactjs using bootstrap Nav?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in reactjs and I would like to link all my pages with the NavBar function I coded.
When i click on the 'Companies' button, the URL changes correctly to 'http://localhost:3000/companies.js' but the page itself doesn't change... Here's the NavBar code:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';


export default function NavBar() {
const handleSelect = (eventKey) => {
    let path={eventKey};
    window.location=path;
};

return (
  <Nav variant="pills" activeKey="/index.js" onSelect={handleSelect}>
    <Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Link eventKey="/index.js" href="/index.js">
        Home
      </Nav.Link>          
    </Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Link eventKey="/login.js" href="/login.js">
        Login
      </Nav.Link>
    </Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link eventKey="/companies.js" href="/companies.js">
        Companies
      </Nav.Link>
    </Nav.Item>
  </Nav>
);
}
```

And here's my Companies.js code as an example:

```
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {ImageGrid} from './charts.js';
import NavBar from './navbar.js';


ReactDOM.render(<div>
<NavBar />
<ImageGrid />
</div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding the component with corresponding links.

The code you have written in companies.js is wrong. This code should be in App.js only.

To navigate from one page to another page, you should have install react-router and then bind each component with the particular link. Then you will be able to access this page.

Please visit the below medium link where you can understand it easily. Hope you got the solution.

https://medium.com/how-to-react/use-react-router-link-with-bootstrap-315a8b88e129

https://faiizii992.medium.com/creating-a-navbar-using-react-router-dom-and-react-bootstrap-react-router-bootstrap-e6b59015a5ec